# getElementsByClassName returns undefined with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, html

I am using getElementsByClassName and it returns `{ '0': {} }`
I tried to use `await page.$$('.my class');` and `document.querySelector(".my class")`, but the class have spaces and it doesn't work.
What can I do?

Comment: CSS classes can't have spaces in their names. If you see `class="my class"`, it means the element has two classes, "my" and "class".

Comment: You don't need to use `await`, it is not async.

Comment: Since classes can't have spaces, you can always just use: `document.querySelector(".my.class")` By adding a period inbetween, you are looking for the FIRST element that has BOTH MY and CLASS. Where as `document.querySelectorAll(".my.class")` gets all of them with BOTH.